# How to enable again disabled components

Tags: android, authentication, progressdialog, disabled-input

When click to login button start proggres bar till i log in.When progress bar is show disabled all edittext and buttons, but if user wrong his name or password , fields stay disabled. My problem is where can i set enable to my components. 
Here is the code:

```
public void loginButton(View v) {
        EditText etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

        email = etEmail.getText().toString();
        password = etPassword.getText().toString();

        if (email.length() > 0 && password.length() > 0) {


             myProgress=0; //veriable for increase time 
             progressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.myProgress);
             progressBar.setVisibility(0); // set visibale false to proggres bar until sign in button is pressed
             /*Do some work in background thread*/ 
             new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    while(progressStatus<2)
                    {
                        progressStatus=performTask();
                        /* Button b = (Button) register;
                        b.setEnabled(false);*/

                    }
                    /*Hides the Progress bar*/
                    myHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            progressBar.setVisibility(8); // set visibale true

                           progressStatus=0; 

                        }
                    });

                }
                /* Do some task*/
                private int performTask()
                {

                    register.setClickable(false);
                    login.setClickable(false);
                    EtEmail.setEnabled(false);
                    EtPassword.setEnabled(false);

                    try {
                        //simulate doing some work
                        Thread.sleep(2500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e)
                        {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return ++myProgress;    
                }
            }).start();

            tryLogin();

        } else {

            // Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email and password.",
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            alertDialogThis = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
            timer = new Timer();
            alertDialogThis.setMessage("Please enter email and password");
            dlg = alertDialogThis.create();
            dlg.show();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    dlg.dismiss(); // when the task active then close the dialog
                    timer.cancel(); // also just top the timer thread,
                                    // otherwise, you may receive a crash report
                }
            }, 2000);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to revert the clickable and enabled states for the elements in your login error handler. Something like would work if called when there is an error logging in.

```
private void onLoginError() {
    register.setClickable(true);
    login.setClickable(true);
    EtEmail.setEnabled(true);
    EtPassword.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Also, for clarity you should be using static constants instead of magic numbers for things like visibility state. For instance, to show you progress bar, use:

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and to hide it later, use:

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```